# Image Placement CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have 4896x421 Image
and i would like to have this image moving 247 to the left "without this img ever ending"
is there a way to repeat the image left and right of the "real" image so that i dont get "white spots" shifting this image?

start position: the div has no "white spots"

https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/32898926/1.png

after a few seconds (white spots on the right side):

https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/32898925/2.png

i edited the image so that if i would take the image to times and would lay them next to each other they look like 1 big image, could i just always fill the div without showing the whole image?

```js
$('#bg1').animate({'left': 1000},10000,'linear');
```

```css
#wrapper {
 top: 75px;
 left: 5px;
 width:1777px;
 height:1000px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position:relative;
}

.bg{
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
}
#bg1{
 background-image: url("../img/bg3.png");
  background-color:#000;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="bg1" class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

ty guys!

Comment: ah sorry right! i wasnt allowed to use more then 2 links i removed it :) https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/32898905/bg3.png

Comment: yeah sorry, im new to html/jquery/css, is my problem clear? ( eng is clearly not my native language sorry :D )

Comment: yeah i saw that question but it didnt help me if i do it like there my whole image is just strechted inside the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

[JSfiddle with comments](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/xbq1v7fg/9/)

```js
$(function() {
  var $image = $('#bg1');
  var imgW = $image.css("background-size").replace('px', ''); //negative number of backgroung image size
  
  //comment out if you want it to move from right to left
  imgW = imgW * -1; 
 var num = 0;

  function animate_img() {
   if (num == 1) {
     num = 0;
      $image.css("background-position-x", "0")
    }
    
    $image.animate({
        backgroundPositionX: imgW + 'px'
      }, 10000, "linear",
      function() {
        num = 1;
        animate_img();
      });
  }
  animate_img();
});
```

```css
.bg {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

#bg1 {
  background: url('https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/32898905/bg3.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
  background-size: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="bg1" class="bg"></div>
</div>
```